# Scala for-comprehension with Options

Tags: scala

I have 2 Scala Options which I need to combine together for further processing. One of them can be None.

I use for comprehension as:

```
val first: Option[Int] = Some(2)
val second: Option[Int] = Some(3) 
val result: Option[String] =  for {
          f <- first
          s <- second
        } yield {
          s"Inputs are $f and $s "
        }
```

But if one of the Option is None, Scala would skip yield block. I want yield to be executed even if there is None. How can it be done? May be I can put some filter in for block which transforms original None to some non-None value.

So basically can it be done:

```
val result: Option[String] =  for {
              f <- first
              s <- second.isDefined else Some(-1)
            } yield {
              // my logic
            }
```

Comment: Rather than using `for` you probably want to use either **pattern matching** or just `getOrElse` on both options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the logic you want to apply in case of a `None` value.

I see two possibilities:

**Use a default value**

```scala
for {
  f <- first
  s <- second.orElse(Some(-1)) // default value -1
} yield {
  s"Inputs are $f and $s "
}
```

This works nice if you want to apply a similar logic in case of a `None` value.

**Use a pattern match**

```scala
(first, second) match {
  case (Some(f), Some(s)) => ...
  case (Some(f), None) => ...
  case (None, Some(s)) => ...
  case (None, None) => ...
}
```

This works better for different behavior in case of `None` but this doesn't "scale" well if you have more than 2 `Option`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
   first.foreach { f => println(s"Inputs are $f and ${second.getOrElse(-1)}") }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this if you want to execute both options.

```
    val firstResult = first match {
      case Some(value) => value
      case _           => -1
    }
    val secondResult = second match {
      case Some(value) => value
      case _           => -1

    }
   Some(s"Inputs are $firstResult and $secondResult ")
```

Comment: This pattern matching is easily replaced with `getOrElse`

Comment: @GaëlJ yes agreed you can do if you don't have to apply some operation on the value